# CentOS 8, Apache 2.4, по 80 порту работает, по 443 - The requested URL /login was not found on this server

Tags: linux, apache, centos

firewall-cmd port 443 открыт.

```
В /etc/httpd/sites-available/site-name.com/**site-name.conf**
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site-name.com
    ServerAlias site-name.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-name.com/html/act/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog /var/www/site-name.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/site-name.com/log/requests.log combined


    <Directory /var/www/site-name.com/html/act/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
а также, **site-name.com.ssl.conf**
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site-name.com
    ServerAlias site-name.com   
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-name.com/html/act/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog /var/www/site-name.com/log/errors_ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/www/site-name.com/log/request.log combined


    <Directory /var/www/site-name.com/html/act/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/9d024ed090ca0.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/sitename.key

</VirtualHost>

В /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/ две ссылки (site-name.com.ssl.conf, site-name.com.conf )
В httpd.conf 
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

mod_ssl установлен.

Спасибо.
П.С. PHP 7.4 Laravel (может пригодится).

Comment: сделай tail -f /var/www/site-name.com/log/errors_ssl.log и смотри в момент запроса на что он тебе пожалуется. у тебя вообще все так с ссл работает или только один локейшн?

Comment: Только здесь. errors_ssl чист.

Comment: и /var/www/site-name.com/log/request.log тоже?

Comment: 192.168.0.107 - - [08/Oct/2020:11:57:32 +0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://172.16.35.132/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.51"

Comment: ну т.е. у тебя запроса логин вообще нет нигде при ссл? а не редиретит ли браузер в простой хттп при неполучении ответа от ссл? глянь other*.log. и логи на 80м порту когда ты посылаешь запрос /login

Comment: перенаправил логи ссл с request.log на request_ssl.log. Apache лог файл создал, но он опять пуст. Такое ощущение, что на вирт хост 443 вообще запросы не идут.

Comment: Странно, https вроде как видит, так как ругается на сертификат.

Comment: в выводе sudo netstat -n -l -p ты видишь апача на 443 порту?

Comment: cat /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log тоже нет ничего?

Comment: Да, апач слушает, я проверял. Тут вот в чем дело, видать ошибка девелопера (или моя), потому как добавляешь /index.php апп запускается.

Comment: чтобы не ругался на сертификат, если у тебя белый ip-адресе и А-запись в DNS есть можно поставить Let's Encrypt, ставишь бота он тебе сам настроит все и сертификат потом будет обновлять автоматом.

Comment: Спасибо большое за реакцию. Сертификат  (wildcard)  есть потом разберусь. Вот почему он браузер по 443 только при добавлении в запрос  /index.php запускает логин, а по 80 сразу запускает логин.

Comment: странно у тебя ихдекс переопределен, попробуй в каталоге логин сделать .htaccess и добавить DirectoryIndex index.php index.html непосредственно туда.

Comment: теста ради сделай index.html с текстом типа оно работает в каталоге /login и посмотри откроется ли он если после логин ничего не указывать.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за советы. Меня несколько дней не было. Сегодня глянул... В общем, во всем виновата моя невнимательность. При конфигурации сервера я, как обычно, сделал бэкапы .conf файлов. И ssl.conf в том числе. И... редактировал ssl.conf.bak. Ну и соответственно, апач забирал конфиги из оригинального файла, игнорируя мной созданный для вирт. хоста.
Вопрос закрыт. Еще раз благодарю.